# Update one table with newly inserted id from another

Tags: mysql

So, the situation is this:

- Table Foo has a foreign key to table Bar.
- There are currently many rows in Foo where this foreign key is null.
- All Foos need a Bar.

I want to:

- For each Foo where bar_fk is null, insert a new row into Bar.
- Update Foo with the newly added id for Bar.

How would you do this in MySQL? Can it be done using straight SQL? Using stored procedures?

Answer (score 2):

The query `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` should help you achieve this.